# Why did only a portion of Mance Rayder's army attack The Wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones, warfare

When the King beyond the wall attacked the wall why did he only send around a 1000 men if he had a 100,000?

Comment: To test the defences, no point wasting your whole force if there are 50k men guarding the wall.

Comment: Where is it stated that he took only 1000?

Comment: Relevant: [Why did Stannis Baratheon emerge victorious against the Wildlings](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138833/why-did-stannis-emerge-victorious-against-wildling-host/138838#138838)

Answer (score 9):

The King beyond the wall had a large number of followers, but they were wildlings, not soldiers. Sending a horde of badly armed unarmoured "civilian" wildlings at a well defended gate would have blocked it with dead in no time.

A much better strategy is to pick your best fighters (and giants) and let them open the gate and clear the defenders. Then bring through the masses.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, Mance was likely expecting the raid on Castle Black from south of the wall to be successful. The giants / mammoths were likely a distraction, or backup plan at worse.

Comment: Probably true, but could you add some information from the show to support this? Perhaps from transcripts, or just description?